# Use a 3rd party gps navigation database

Tags: api, navigation, gps

I want to develop an app for iOS that integrates a gps navigation widget (like Waze). Is there a 3rd party company that provides such an api (free/paid)?

Comment: I found this api: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Directions]. Anybody used that?